# Python - wrong syntax. TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Tags: python

I'm trying to code some file distribution script:
The script receives the file/dir to distribute as var 'filename', the destination path as 'path' and then should run through all servers listed in srv.list and scp the file/dir to each one of them. In addition there's that ropt which is used if the user input is a dir rather than a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
dirList = os.listdir("./")
srvlist = os.system("cat srv.lst")
filename = raw_input("Please enter file/dir to distribute")
path = raw_input("Please enter destination path")
ropt = ()
for d in dirList:
    if os.path.isdir(d) == True:
        ropt = "-r"
        os.system("/usr/bin/scp " (ropt)"-- "(filename)" "(srvlist)":"(path)
    else:
        os.system("/usr/bin/scp "(filename)" "(srvlist)":"(path))
```

Output:

```
Please enter file/dir to distribute: 1.py
Please enter destination path: /root/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 13, in ?
    os.system("/usr/bin/scp "+filename+" "+srvlist+":"+path)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
[root@g1-lon distribute]#
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Your hashbang (#!python) seems unlike to be correct.

Comment: In general, not sanitizing user input before passing it to a shell command is a bad idea.

Comment: I'm asking the questions because i'm trying to learn, if you come and unvote my question at least write why.

Comment: Your question was downvoted (not by me) because you pasted in a code block without explaining what you were trying to achieve or the error message. SO appreciates questions written out in full sentences.

Comment: There are other faults but I hesitate to correct them due to the possible security problems pointed out in the comments.  And your intention isn't clear.  Perhaps for some twisted reason you want to input some data and then whatever the data is run the command "/usr/bin/scp ropt -- filename srvlist"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is definitely not valid:

```
os.system("/usr/bin/scp " (ropt)"-- "(filename)" "(srvlist)":"(path)
```

It's missing a training paren.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but assuming you fix that error, perhaps you could use interpolation):

```
os.system("/usr/bin/scp %s -- %s %s:%s" % (ropt, filename, srvlist, path))
```

Comment: You're right, I've added another ')' at the end of the line but it still doesn't work, I've edited the question with the error output

Answer (score 2):

```
os.system("/usr/bin/scp "+ ropt+"-- "+filename+" "+srvlist+":"+path)
```

The `+` sign is used for concatenation